# how to filter the required text from the output of command in shell?

Tags: shell

im trying to filter newly added drives like da0,da1...(depends on hard disk type)etc. this should be happen through dynamically like if i run `ls /dev/ | grep "da\|ada\|vtbd\|nvd"` i should get only newly added drive or unmounted drives. so i need to delete mounted drive and should filter unmounted drives. how to filter this using sed or awk command?

```
root@ostest:~ # lsblk
DEVICE         MAJ:MIN SIZE TYPE                              LABEL MOUNT
da0              0:93  5.0G zfs                                   - -
da1              0:104 5.0G zfs                                   - -
da2              0:105 5.0G zfs                                   - -
da3              0:107 5.0G zfs                                   - -
vtbd0            0:87   50G GPT                                   - -
  vtbd0p1        0:89  256K freebsd-boot       gptid/0599c6ae-5f2f-11eb-a6b0-1707445d9baa -
  vtbd0p2        0:90  2.0G freebsd-swap                  gpt/swap0 -
  vtbd0p3        0:91   48G freebsd-zfs                   gpt/disk0 <ZFS>
vtbd1            0:88  482K cd9660                 iso9660/config-2 /var/lib/cloud/seed/config_drive
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following command for listing unmounted volumes:

```
lsblk  --noheadings --raw | awk '{print substr($0,0,4)}' | uniq -c | grep 1 | awk '{print "/dev/"$2}' | grep -E "(/dev/.*)[[:digit:]]"
```

With this command we are listing all the partitions ignoring the disks by using `grep -E "(/dev/.*)[[:digit:]]`.